# How can I accept 0/0/0 as a valid Date in WPF DatePicker?

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I have a DatePicker and I want to allow user to enter 00/00/0000. If I enter 00/00/0000 it does not accept it and makes the DatePicker text null/blank again.

The DatePicker already has a converter attached to it that Converts the bound value to MM/dd/yyyy format and also checks for non null values and ConvertsBack to MMddyyyy during user input.

As pointed out, I know 00/00/0000 is not a valid value for DateTime but is there any way to fake 01/01/0001 to be displayed as 00/00/0000 using styles or some other way?

Basically according to the needs of the client, null should represent- no value was entered and 00000000 should represent- value was unknown at the time of data entry. I know it does not make sense but I guess at times that is part of a developer's job - to fulfill unrealistic requirements. Textbox is easy option but If its possible via DatePicker then better.

```
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    If Not ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(New DependencyObject) Then
        If value IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim str As String = value.ToString
            Try
                Dim dt As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MMddyyyy", New CultureInfo("en-US"), Nothing)

                Return dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
            Catch ex As Exception
                If str.Trim = "" Then
                    Return Nothing
                Else
                    Return str
                End If
            End Try

        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If

    End If
    Return value.ToString
End Function


Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Return System.Convert.ToDateTime(value).ToString("MMddyyyy")
End Function
```

Comment: Let's assume you somehow manage to let DatePicker accept 00/00/0000. Now, the big question would be: What date is 00/00/0000 actually? Hmm, it isn't a date, isn't it...? (with respect to Gregorian calendar)

Comment: You can only set the SelectedDate value of a DatePicker to a DateTime value or null. 00/00/0000 is neither.

Comment: As a side note: In Gregorian calendar, the first year AD is the year 1 (=1AD). The year preceding 1AD is not year zero. It is 1BC.

Comment: I know 00/00/0000 is not a valid date. I need to mask it. Here is what I have in my mind; I can allow 1/1/0001 and mask it to be displayed as 00/00/0000? The converter along with the mask can achieve this I assume?

But its not accepting 01/01/0001 as well. I set the  DisplayDateStart="1/1/0001".

Answer (score 0):

> If I enter 00/00/0000 it does not accept it and makes the DatePicker text null/blank again.

That's because the `SelectedDate` property of the `DatePicker` control is a `DateTime?`. This means that you can *only* set it to a valid `DateTime` value or null (`default(DateTime?)`). 00/00/0000 is neither.

You *cannot* set a `DateTime?` field to 00/00/0000 just as little as you can set an `int` field to "abc" or a `DateTime?` to "cde". This is simply not a valid value for the data type.

If you want to be able to do this you better use a `TextBox` that you can enter any `string` value into and then convert this `string` to a `DateTime` as needed. There is a `Calendar` control that you can use together with the `TextBox` for the user to be able to selected a date.

Comment: I'm looking more towards ideas similar to masking it or some sort of out of the box ideas to get this done. Going to edit my question to reflect this. Thank you for the information and suggestion on using textbox with calendar.

Comment: You can't "get this done" using the built-in DatePicker control for the reasons I mentioned in my answer. That's also why I suggested not to use this control but for example a TextBox.